# Create database view from django model

Tags: django, sql-view

I learned sql "view" as a virtual table to facilitate the SQL operations,  like

```
MySQL [distributor]> CREATE VIEW CustomerEMailList AS
    -> SELECT cust_id, cust_name, cust_email
    -> FROM Customers
    -> WHERE cust_email IS NOT NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.026 sec)

MySQL [distributor]> select * from customeremaillist;
+------------+---------------+-----------------------+
| cust_id    | cust_name     | cust_email            |
+------------+---------------+-----------------------+
| 1000000001 | Village Toys  | sales@villagetoys.com |
| 1000000003 | Fun4All       | jjones@fun4all.com    |
| 1000000004 | Fun4All       | dstephens@fun4all.com |
| 1000000005 | The Toy Store | kim@thetoystore.com   |
| 1000000006 | toy land      | sam@toyland.com       |
+------------+---------------+-----------------------+
5 rows in set (0.014 sec)
```

When I checked the Django documentation subsequently, there are no such functionality to create a virtual "model table" which could simplify the data manipulation.

Should I forget the virtual table "view" when using Django ORM?

Comment: There is an extension `django-database-view`s for that: https://pypi.org/project/django-database-view/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Django has - as far as I know at the moment - no builtin support for views.

But you *can* construct such views, by using the [**`django-database-view`**](https://pypi.org/project/django-database-view/) package.

After installing the package (for example with pip):

```
 pip install django-database-view
```

Furthermore the `dbview` app has to be registered in the `settings.py` file:

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'dbview',
    # ...
)
```

Now you can construct a view, this looks a bit *similar* to the construction of a model, except that you need to implement a `view(..)` function that specifies the query behind the view. Something similar to:

```
from django.db import models
from dbview.models import DbView

class CustomerEMailList(DbView):
    cust = models.OneToOneField(Customer, primary_key=True)
    cust_name = models.CharField()
    cust_email = models.CharField()

    @classmethod
    def view(klass):
        qs = (Customers.objects.filter(cust_email__isnull=False)
                               .values('cust_id', 'cust_name', 'cust_email'))
        return str(qs.query)
```

Now we can make a migrations:

```
./manage.py makemigrations
```

Now in the migration, we need to **make a change**: the calls to **`migrations.CreateModel`** that are related to the constructed view(s), should be changed to the **`CreateView`** of the `dbview` module. Something that looks like:

```
from django.db import migrations
from dbview import CreateView

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = []

    operations = [
        CreateView(
            name='CustomerEMailList',
            fields=[
                # ...
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: The core functionality of the `django-database-view` package is contained in a total of 42 lines (at this moment), so it may be interesting just to cherry-pick from the [source](https://github.com/manuelnaranjo/django-database-view/blob/master/dbview/helpers.py) and adapt to your needs, instead of introducing the external dependency.

Comment: I think this package is broken, this does not work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is able only for MySQL database :(

Comment: Thank you my friend. Just note that you need to import 'dbview.models', not just 'dbview'. So, the second line must be replaced to 'from dbview.models import DbView'

Comment: seems from django 3.2 the reference to CreateView has changed..
from dbview import CreateView has changed to:
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

Comment: @Sindhujit: no, this is not a class-based view, but a database view, that thus originates from the `dbview` module, not one of the modules of Django.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ok . So now I installed dbview from pypi and also db2py, but it complains that ImportError: cannot import name 'db2py'

Comment: This solution will let you both manage (i.e., create) your views with Django and make them available in your Django app. You cannot modify views though with this, here's a [fork of the repo](https://github.com/Seriouskosk/django-database-view/tree/master) with DropView implemented as well.

Answer (score 23):

According to the [Django ORM Cookbook by Agiliq](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/database_view.html), you can do it like the following.

Create a view in the database:

```sql
create view temp_user as
select id, first_name from auth_user;
```

Create a model which is **not managed** and naming a db_table explicitly:

```py
class TempUser(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "temp_user"
```

You'll be able to query then, but you'll receive an error once you try to update.

Query like always:

```py
TempUser.objects.all().values()
```

I haven't tried this yet, but I certainly will.

Comment: Interesting hidden feature this. Note that you need an id field in the view, even if you don't reference it in the model, otherwise Django will complain. Also take for example a multi-table view based on a join... you don't even need to reference all the fields in the view, just the primary keys, then declare them as ForeignKey fields in the Django view model and let Django do all the relationship handling and lazy loading.

Comment: This solution is good if you do not want to manage (i.e., create/modify) your views with Django but just make them available.

Answer (score 3):

I created a Django plugin which you can create a view table. You can check it [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-view-table/), on pypi.org

Install with `pip install django-view-table` and set `INSTALLED_APPS` like this:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'viewtable',
]
```

And so, a view table model can be written as follows:

```py
from django.db import models
from view_table.models import ViewTable

# Base table
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)


# View table
class Books(ViewTable):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    count = models.IntegerField()

    @classmethod
    def get_query(self):
        # Select sql statement
        return Book.objects.values('category').annotate(count=models.Count('category')).query
```

Finally, create the table:

```sh
python manage.py createviewtable
```