# Accessing MySQL Views in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

**How can I access a MySQL view in Django?**

I find it hard to believe that I am the first to want to do this with Django, but because both Django and MySQL use the term 'view' the search results have not been helpful. I have read the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#calling-stored-procedures) on running raw SQL queries and accessing stored procedures, but it doesn't quite solve my particular need.

Basically, there are several MySQL views in the database that I need to manage/access via Django like I can with tables. I realize that I can access views by running raw SQL queries in Django, but I value the control Django models and migrations provide and would like to be able to do the same with views.

Ideally, I would like the official Django way of doing this but if that doesn't exist I would also value your hacks/workarounds for this.

Comment: Create a matching model, set the [model option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/) `managed=False` and make sure to adapt other things like the table name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create database view from django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51817841/create-database-view-from-django-model)

Comment: @KlausD. could you elaborate on that? The documentation makes it sound like it is the same implementation as a model other than this flag, but doesn't clarify how I would map the fields of this unmanaged model to the columns of a separate table that is managed.

Comment: TomCarrick the accepted answer does look like it may work, but I'd prefer a solution not requiring 3rd-party plugins. However, the unaccepted answer looks more promising to me and may have actually just clarified what I wasn't understanding about @KlausD.'s comment.